# Upload images PHP to MySQL and retrieve correct images to each form

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have to re-explain my situation they said.

my html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="carform.css"/>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="connection.php" method="post" class="smart-green">
<h1> Car listing
 <span>Please fill all the text in the fields.</span>
 </h1>
<label>
<span>Make:</span>
<select id="category">
 <option value="Alfa Romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
 <option value="Aston Martin">Aston Martin</option>
 <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
 <option value="Austin">Austin</option>
 <option value="Bentley">Bentley</option>
 <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
 <option value="Buddy">Buddy</option>
 <option value="Buick">Buick</option>
 <option value="Cadillac">Cadillac</option>
 <option value="Chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>  
 <option value="Chrysler">Chrysler</option>
 <option value="Citroen">Citroen</option>
 <option value="Dacia">Dacia</option>
 <option value="Daewoo">Daewoo</option>
 <option value="Daihatsu">Daihatsu</option>
 <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
 <option value="Ferrari">Ferrari</option>
 <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
 <option value="Fisker">Fisker</option>
 <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
 <option value="GMC">GMC</option>
 <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
 <option value="Hummer">Hummer</option>
 <option value="Hyundai">Hyundai</option>
 <option value="Infiniti">Infiniti</option>
 <option value="Isuzu">Isuzu</option>
 <option value="Iveco">Iveco</option>
 <option value="Jaguar">Jaguar</option>
 <option value="Jeep">Jeep</option>
 <option value="Kewet">Kewet</option>
 <option value="Kia">Kia</option>
 <option value="Koenigsegg">Koenigsegg</option>
 <option value="Lada">Lada</option>
 <option value="Lamborghini">Lamborghini</option>
 <option value="Lancia">Lancia</option>
 <option value="Land Rover">Land Rover</option>
 <option value="Lexus">Lexus</option>
 <option value="Lincoln">Lincoln</option>
 <option value="Lotus">Lotus</option>
 <option value="Maserati">Maserati</option>
 <option value="Maybach">Maybach</option>
 <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>
 <option value="McLaren">McLaren</option>
 <option value="Mercedes-Benz">Mercedes-Benz</option>
 <option value="Mercury">Mercury</option>
 <option value="MG">MG</option>
 <option value="MINI">MINI</option>
 <option value="Mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
 <option value="Morgan">Morgan</option>
 <option value="Morris">Morris</option>
 <option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
 <option value="Oldsmobile">Oldsmobile</option>
 <option value="Opel">Opel</option>
 <option value="Peugeot">Peugeot</option>
 <option value="Piaggio">Piaggio</option>
 <option value="Plymouth">Plymouth</option>
 <option value="Pontiac">Pontiac</option>
 <option value="Porsche">Porsche</option>
 <option value="Renault">Renault</option>
 <option value="Reva">Reva</option>
 <option value="Rolls Royce">Rolls Royce</option>
 <option value="Rover">Rover</option>
 <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="Seat">Seat</option>
 <option value="Skoda">Skoda</option>
 <option value="Smart">Smart</option>
 <option value="Ssangyong">Ssangyong</option>
 <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option>
 <option value="Suzuki">Suzuki</option>
 <option value="Tazzari">Tazzari</option>
 <option value="Tesla">Tesla</option>
 <option value="Think">Think</option>
 <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
 <option value="Triumph">Triumph</option>
<option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
<option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="Others">Others</option>
</select>
</label>
<label>
<span>Title:</span>
<input id="title" type="text" name="title">
</label>
<label>
<span>Price:</span> 
<input id="price" type="text" name="price">$
</label>   <label>
<span>Description:</span>
<textarea id="description" name="description" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>
</label>
<label>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Send"/>
</label>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

and my php:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to mysqli: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$cat = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['category']);
$tit = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['title']);
$pri = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['price']);
$des = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['description']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO forsale (Category, Title, Price, Description)        VALUES     ('$cat', '$tit', '$pri', '$des')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));

echo "1 record added";


mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Now what I am missing is having uploading maximum of 12 images for this form per Id and being able to retrieve all the images that belongs to eash posting

Comment: Really not understand what do you want to say.

Comment: @Sachink: I do not understand either. And the option values seems to be very important, so that they are named twice :-)

Comment: If I can upload images in the same table and the same form or do I have to upload images using a different form and table?if so how do I retrieve the correct images belonging to the correct id

Comment: do you want a user to be able to upload images to your server, which you want to retrieve later? If so, what you do is add an upload button to the form [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). You note the location of the file where it is uploaded, then set a hidden input with the image location as its value (<input name='location' value='../Images/Cars/Ferrari.png'. Have a column in your database called "image location" and add appropriate sql to the database. When you retrieve data from the databse later, just use this coulmns value as the src (<img src='*HERE*'>)

Comment: Thank you Truvia. Very clever way to perform this task. As you have already established, I a beginner in this field. I read the link from w3school you posted, but I cannot see where and how I should apply the "image location" in the upload script. And should I use a seperated phpfile for mye form action or can I use the upload with my text forms?

Comment: If u look the tutorial - u can copy the input type="file" in ur form to enable the upload of the image. Now in the target file (the second one in ur post) u'll need to add the 'upload php script' from w3schools and modify the variables (dir, post variable to get name of files,etc...). When u fixed single upload file - u could check http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php for multiple upload

Answer (score 0):

your code `if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));`

you are missing a closing curly brace like this, not sure if this is your onle problem but it certainly is a problem.

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));}
```